# Has MongoDB passed DISA certification

Tags: mongodb

I'm interested whether MongoDB is DISA certified.

I found a thread on this here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mil-oss/gxu_wV3SG7U

But I can't understand what the final resolution on this is.

Thanks.

Comment: Department of Internet Scale Agency has certified MongoDB as "Web Scale"

Comment: @ta.speot.is I think you missed the point completely

Comment: I think asking there is a better choice than here.

Comment: By DISA I meant - Defense Information Systems Agency